# Core Plot crashing when calling reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-plot

I am using the core plot library and having a major issue in regards to reloading data.

I have a view that just displays 2 static graphs and that is working fine. However I have another view that needs to update the table.

Not really sure how much information I need to provide as the classes are big. So will start off small and will add more if required.

The way I have it works is I have an NSArray that contains placeholder NSNull values.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)organisationsToDisplay 
{
    if (_organisationsToDisplay == nil) {
        NSNull *placeHolder = [NSNull null];
        _organisationsToDisplay = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder, nil];
    }
    return _organisationsToDisplay;
 }
```

I have this as I am using it to hold 2 objects all of the time and add up to 3 comparators. The two objects always held are added straight away. The other 3 remain as [NSNull values]. I check if a particular object in the array is an NSNull and if so I replace it with the selected object. The below code is called to make the necessary changes before I call reloadData:

```
- (void)updateGraphWithNewComparator:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.organisationsToDisplay count]; i++) {
        if (self.organisationsToDisplay[i] == [NSNull null]) {
            self.organisationsToDisplay[i] = self.comparatorList[indexPath.row];
            [self.organisationKeyViews[i] setHidden:NO];
            [self.organisationKeyViews[i] titleLabel].text = [self.comparatorList[indexPath.row] name];
            break;
        }
     }
    [self updateGraph:Unknown];
}
```

This allows me to have gaps in my graph if someone selects the first comparator, then a second comparator and then deselect the first comparator.

This was working on the simulator on 5.1.1 but would not work on the device. As soon as you clicked a comparator it would crash. Now I have upgraded to xcode 6 it is doing the same thing on the simulator.

Also since upgrading to Xcode 6 I get the following error: **Assertion failed: (CGFloatIsValid(x) && CGFloatIsValid(y)), function void CGPathMoveToPoint(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 254.**

Here is the thread when it crashes:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help. If you need anymore information please don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT**

Here is my base classes implementation of these 2 methods. I then override these in each class to provide the data. The app crashes with this base version.

I check if the object to be used is of type organisation as if I don't it complains about it being an NSNull object. The second placeholder has a lot of arrays as I am having to do a comparison graph.

```
#pragma mark Populating and updating arrays
// Method needs to be overwritten to produce different data.
- (NSArray *)populateDataArray:(Organisation *)organisation option:(DataOptions)selectedOption
{
    if (selectedOption == PlaceholderOne) {
        if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
            return @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                     ];
        }
    }
else if (selectedOption == PlaceHolderTwo) {
    if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
        return @[@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:40],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:60],
                   ], @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:60],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:40],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]
                        ], @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:40],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:60],
                             ], @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:40],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:60],
                                  ]];
    }
}
else if (selectedOption == PlaceholderThree) {
    if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
        return @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:50]];
    }
}
else if (selectedOption == PlaceholderFour) {
    if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
        return @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:50]];
    }
}

return nil;
```

}

```
#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [self.organisationValues count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

if ((fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) && (index < [self.organisationValues count])) {
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"national"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"organisational"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"comparatorOne"]) {
        return self.comparatorOneValues[index];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"comparatorTwo"]) {
        return self.comparatorTwoValues[index];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"comparatorThree"]) {
        return self.comparatorThreeValues[index];
    }

    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"natYear2011"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][0];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"orgYear2011"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][1];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"natYear2012"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][2];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"orgYear2012"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][3];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"natYear2013"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][4];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"orgYear2013"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][5];
    }
    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"orgYear2013"]) {
        return self.organisationValues[index][6];
    }
}

return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:index];
```

}

If you need anymore information please let me know. Many thanks.

**EDIT 2**

Here is an example of an overridden class. I have changed had to change the names of the data and switch statements:

```
#pragma mark Populating and updating arrays
- (NSArray *)populateDataArray:(Organisation *)organisation option:(DataOptions)selectedOption
{
    if (selectedOption == DATA_ONE) {
        if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
            return @[organisation.population.rate_20_25,
                     organisation.population.rate_26_30,
                     organisation.population.rate_31_35,
                     organisation.population.rate_36_40

    }
    }
    else if (selectedOption == DATA_TWO) {
        return nil;
    }
    else if (selectedOption == DATA_THREE) {
        if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
            return @[organisation.population.rate_20_40];
        }
    }
    else if (selectedOption == DATA_FOUR) {
        if ([organisation isKindOfClass:[Organisation class]]) {
            return @[organisation.population.rate_20_50];
        }
    }

    return nil;
    }
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the plot data. Please show the datasource methods and the values being returned from them.

Comment: I suspect the plot data being sent to your graphs isn't what you expect. The plot should skip over any `NSNull` or `NAN` values. It's also possible that the plot ranges or the bar plot setup are causing `NAN` bar coordinates. What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.5.1.

I will check to see if the plot ranges might be causing an issue.

I have added an edit to my question to show an overridden version of my data source.

Comment: I did write a comment I deleted which I am not sure you will have seen. By removing the checks for organisation in my base class it worked because I was passing in an id. Or it worked by passing in an organisation object. Therefore I am pretty certain it's to do with the data I'm returning from my datasource method.

I have added an edit to my question to show an overridden version of my data source as well.

I will investigate further on Monday as I don't have a device on me this weekend. If I still have problems I will update the question. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have come up with a solution to the issue Eric. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to stop it from crashing.

If the passed in object was not an Organisation object I was just returning nil. This seemed to cause unexpected behaviour. I am instead now returning a dummy object. In my case it's an array of zero values.

```
- (NSArray *)emptyDataForNullGraph
{
    NSNumber *zero = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    return @[zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero];
}
```

This is working for me. Not sure if it's the most elegant solution.